# Information in jLabel auto joined into one sentence

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I trying to some formatting for my label in java swing. If user enter :

```
    This
    is
    testing.
```

And I store this into database and retrieve out. How can I make this prevent from auto joining into one sentence. For example, I want this to be shown on my label which is scrollable :

```
    This
    is
    testing.
```

instead of Thisistesting. I do not know what is this called. Is this the line wrap method? I added this : jLabel_reply.setLineWrap(true); into my code but no luck. The sentence is still auto joined together. Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "on my label which is scrollable"? In your label or text area?

Comment: It is label. Sorry sorry I copied the wrong code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JLabel` does not display itself on multiple lines by default.

You have two options here:

1) Use a non-editable, non-opaque `JTextArea`

2) Use HTML inside your `JLabel` and replace all your line separators with `<br>`

Basic example illustrating my saying:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestMultipleLineLabel {

    private static final String TEXT = "This is\na text\non multiple lines";

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestMultipleLineLabel.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText(getHTMLText(TEXT));
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setLineWrap(false);
        textArea.setOpaque(false);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(false);
        textArea.setText(TEXT);
        panel.add(textArea, gbc);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private String getHTMLText(String text) {
        return "<html>" + text.replace("\n", "<br>") + "</html>";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestMultipleLineLabel().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I replace the label with text area and it works now. Thanks for the guides!

Comment: But how can I force the jScrollPane always display the data on top? When I enter the app, the scroll pane of textarea automatically snap to the bottom. I tried with this : jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0); But it does not work

Comment: @Newbies Do you need a wrapping `JScrollPane`? Otherwise you can use this: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    textArea.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle());
   }
  });`

Comment: I tried with : jTextArea_content.setCaretPosition(0); and jScrollPane_descContent.getViewport().setViewPosition(new java.awt.Point(0, 0)); which I get from research but all does not work

Comment: All three methods above does not work. My scroll bar still automatically snap to the bottom of text area when user first enter the window

Answer (score 0):

Your database engine probably trims your line separators. You should probably use a field type that supports special characters like \n.

Comment: But I am currently using microsoft access and java swing. There is no nvarchar in the list of data type. I am using Text instead of nvarchar

Comment: Hard to guess what you are using. As I said, the field value probably removes line separators.

Comment: It works after I replace my label with textarea. Thanks for the guides!

Comment: so what am I supposed to do if I wan to add a new space on every new line and store it into database? since ms access has only text data type.